# Should I open/close a file repeatedly or keep it open for an extended period of time (~1 week)?

Tags: python, hdf5, scientific-computing, h5py

I'm implementing data collection for a Markov chain Monte Carlo inversion program. However, the MCMC runs can take a week or more to complete! Would it be better to open the file at the beginning of the run:

```
with h5py.File('my_data.hdf5', 'r+', libver='latest') as fp:
    fp.swmr_mode = True
    mcmc_run(fp)
```

Or each time I want to add a dataset (inside `mcmc_run()`)

```
with h5py.File('my_data.hdf5', 'r+', libver='latest') as fp:
    fp.swmr_mode = True
    fp['dataset'] = new_data
```

I have to save about 7 mb over 9 datasets for each acceptance (500 total over about a week of computation time, ~5000 iterations). Unfortunately the data is coming from several different objects inside the iteration so I can't group them and open the file once per acceptance.

Comment: I don't know h5py, but data is usually flushed (like a commit) on close, so it would be safer to close.  However you might have a `flush` operation available, so that would have the same effect.  The problem with closing is that you loose the file position, but you should be prepared for restarts caused by power outages etc.

Comment: @cdarke The nice thing about hdf5 is that there's no issue with losing file position. Datasets are accessed somewhat like a numpy array in a dictionary. There is a flush operation. Currently I flush after each dataset change.

Comment: For runs that take that long, you may want to consider what happens if you have a power outtage (as an MC veteran, this is my biggest fear).  It seems like closing and re-opening the file is probably safer, and less likely to leave the file vulnerable to corruption during a power outtage, computer crash, etc.

Comment: @gariepy That's a good point. I will do the safe thing and open/close the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Posting comment as an answer]

For runs that take that long, you may want to consider what happens if you have a power outage (as an MC veteran, this is my biggest fear). I recommend closing and re-opening the file because it is probably safer, and less likely to leave the file vulnerable to corruption during a power outage, computer crash, etc. when running over many days.